# How does terraform handle mounting an AWS Elastic Block Store (EBS) with regards to partitioning?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, devops, aws-ebs

Sample terraform code snippet for mounting an EBS (just for context):

```
resource "aws_ebs_volume" "ebs-volume-1" {
  availability_zone = "eu-central-1a"
  size              = 20
  type              = "gp2"
  tags = {
    Name = "extra volume data"
  }
}

resource "aws_volume_attachment" "ebs-volume-1-attachment" {
  device_name = "/dev/xvdh"
  volume_id   = aws_ebs_volume.ebs-volume-1.id
  instance_id = aws_instance.example.id
}
```

I have read through the terraform documentation on attributes it has for mounting EBS [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/ebs_volume.html); however, it is not clear to me how does that block device gets partitioned (or if partitioning here is relevant at all.

Explanation of what is EBS: [here](https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "aws_ebs_volume" resource will create the EBS volume, the "aws_volume_attachment" puts it on an EC2 instance.

Keep in mind, you can do this in an "aws_instance" resource as well.